# Auto Select Single Match jQuery UI Autocomplete Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I am using a slightly popular Combobox UI element which is a custom jQuery UI Autocomplete extension: [see here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

I would like, if there is a single match to select that match and also fire the selected event, specifically changing this section of code in the Autocomplete Combobox should be the solution:

```
    _source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                        return {
                            label: text,
                            value: value,
                            option: this
                        };
                }));
            }
```

I am not familiar with the jQuery map function, its syntax does not feel familiar to me even though I am very familiar with jQuery and vanilla Javascript, though I understand what the function is doing.

I would like to something like:

```
if(match.count == 1)
   //fire select event and/or select option in hidden select list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = [
  "Apple",
  "Orange",
  "Pineapple",
  "Strawberry",
  "Mango"
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#fruits" ).autocomplete({
        source: data,
        autoFocus: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use code in HTML as follows                                   <form>
    <!-- textbox and label that are attached with the autocomplete -->
      <label for="fruits">Fruit <input type="text" name="fruits" id="fruits" /></label>
</form>

Comment: Major props sir or mam, a much needed answer!! My sincere thanks.